# Does aws-sdk for javascript supports the multipart "Downloads" from S3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I need to download a large set of images from an S3 bucket using `aws-sdk-js`.

Now I'm doing it by calling the `s3.getObject(params, function (err, data)`. in a loop for each and every file in my list?

**Is there any other faster and efficient method to download the files other than downloading them one by one in `aws-sdk-js`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you would want to sync your directory on the s3 bucket

you could use [`aws s3 sync`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) from aws CLI or [`s3cmd put --recursive`](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-sync) from s3cmd CLI

If you want to use the aws-sdk-js there's no sync method from the API, fortunately, many have made this functionality.

for example the [node-s3-client](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client) has such functionality

```
var params = {
  localDir: "some/local/dir",
  deleteRemoved: true, // default false, whether to remove s3 objects
                       // that have no corresponding local file.

  s3Params: {
    Bucket: "s3 bucket name",
    Prefix: "some/remote/dir/",
    // other options supported by putObject, except Body and ContentLength.
    // See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property
  },
};
var uploader = client.uploadDir(params);
uploader.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error("unable to sync:", err.stack);
});
uploader.on('progress', function() {
  console.log("progress", uploader.progressAmount, uploader.progressTotal);
});
uploader.on('end', function() {
  console.log("done uploading");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I really wanted to download some selected set of files from a s3 bucket, based on a user input given via a web application. As of now I'm considering the option to  use a lambda function which returns pre-signed set of URLs from the s3 bucket, rather than getting the files downloaded directly from the web application, due to some security issues. Btw Hope It's possible to use the code snippet you've given to download the data from s3 as well?

Comment: yes you can use the snipped to download, just change `uploadDir` to `downloadDir`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Node JS s3fs module which provides functions that are similar to the fs module. To download multiple files I recommend you to use s3fs module which is simple and easy to use. You can write your files in a directory on your s3 bucket using s3fs and then use the readdirp function:

```
    var fsImpl = new S3FS('test-bucket', options);
    fsImpl.readdirp('test-folder').then(function(files) {
        // Files contains a list of all of the files similar to [`fs.readdir(path, callback)`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback) but with recursive contents 
    }, function(reason) {
       // Something went wrong 
    });
```

source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3fs

To set up s3fs check out the link below, it's pretty easy to use:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3fs